# Dependency injection in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a question about a proper way of structuring the dependencies.

Imagine that you have a web api controller, which has a single method with two parameters: id and bar.
Controller needs to read a specific configuration based on 'id' value, and make a request to a different service with that configuration applied.

```
    public class FooController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;
        private readonly IService _service;

        public FooController(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, IService service)
       {
             _configurationProvider = configurationProvider;
             _service = service;
       }

        public IHttpActionResult Bar(int id, int bar)
        {
            var configuration = _configurationProvider.GetConfiguration(id);
            _service.Configure(configuration);
            var barResult = _service.Bar(bar);

            return Ok(barResult);
        }
}
```

I'm not quite sure that I'm doing it right in terms of dependency injection:

- The service is initialized in the constructor, but the configuration
  is not known until the request is performed. Client of the service
  might not call Configure and it might cause issues (*Would some kind
  of a Builder pattern work here?*).
- Should the service itself take care of it's configuration loading?

Are there any other issues in this example from the dependency injection perspective?

Thanks.

Comment: The structure of your dependencies seems wrong.  The controller is dependent on an IConfigurationProvider, but doesn't actually do anything but pass the retrieved configuration off to a service that it's also dependent on.  Also dependencies shouldn't be infrastructure code, IConfigurationProvider looks like infrastructure code bleeding into your controller.  So really what should happen is that those infrastructure concerns should be handled in your component registration code.

Comment: it would also be good to know what IoC container your are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a factory class (a builder class is probably the wrong thing)

```
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IService> _services = new Dictionary<int, IService>();
    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;

    public ServiceFactory(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    {
        _configurationProvider = configurationProvider;
    }

    public IService GetService(int id)
    {
        if (!_services.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            var config = _configurationProvider.GetConfiguration(id);
            var service = new Service(config);
            _services.Add(id, service);
        }

        return _services[id];
    }
}
```

This will create an instance of the service and keep a reference to it for the lifetime of the factory class so it only has to be created once. Then register and inject the ServiceFactory into your controller.

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public FooController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Bar(int id, int bar)
    {
        var service = _serviceFactory.GetService(id);
        var barResult = service.Bar(bar);

        return Ok(barResult);
    }
}
```

Now your controller is still testable and you don't have to worry about Configure() being called as the 'id' is a dependency on the service constructor.

P.S. No disrespect to @Ahmed Sherien, but don't use Unity, it's old and slow!!!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In those cases I would use a keyed resolve ... something like this if you are using unity:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationType1>("Type1");
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationType2>("Type2");


IConfiguration cfg1 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("Type1");  // return ConfigurationType1 object
IConfiguration cfg2 = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>("Type2"); // return ConfigurationType2 object
```

in your case the implementation will look like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public FooController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Bar(int id, int bar)
    {
        var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>(id.ToString());
        _service.Configure(configuration);
        var barResult = _service.Bar(bar);

        return Ok(barResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the container directly inside of the controller could be a bad idea, firstly now your controller is un-testable (if you ever wanted to test your controllers) it actually reminds me of the service locator pattern which is horrible, secondly your code could now be tightly coupled to your chosen IoC container. And in your code example where does the 'container' variable come from?

Comment: @matt_lethargic I would've defined it in a global variable, but apparently it will be a bad idea too ...

Comment: Yeah in global variable is still bad and still makes your controller untestable